# Spring Boot Pagination

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination

I'm facing the problem for pagination data. Page data is getting calculated using the outer array `dXPRecommendationResponses` where I want it should be calculated through the nested array `recommendations`. I've mentioned the response data in result section.

I tried to change the page data calculation but it is getting calculated using the the data which we are passing in `PageImpl()` constructor.

I've used this approach to paginate the data which we are getting from third party API.

But it is getting calculated using the `dxpRecommendationslist`.

```
#This is the code through I need to generate the response
List<DXPRecommendationResponse> dxpRecommendationslist = new ArrayList<>();

List<DXPActivity> dxpActivities = getThirdResponse(pageable, correlationId,
dxpRecommendationslist, reservationGuestId, reservationId, nbxRecommendationRequest);

return new PageImpl<>(dxpRecommendationslist, pageable, dxpActivities.size());

#This method is used to get data from third party
public List<DXPActivity> getThirdResponse(final Pageable pageable, final String correlationId,
        List<DXPRecommendationResponse> list, String reservationGuestId, String reservationId,
        NBXRecommendationRequest nbxRecommendationRequest) {

    List<DXPActivity> dxpActivities = new ArrayList<>();

    NBXRecommendationResponse nbxRecommendationResponse = vVNBXRecommendationService
            .getCalendarRecommendation(nbxRecommendationRequest, correlationId);

    if (nbxRecommendationResponse != null) {

        DXPRecommendationResponse dxpRecommendationResponse = new DXPRecommendationResponse();
        dxpRecommendationResponse.setReservationGuestId(reservationGuestId);
        dxpRecommendationResponse.setReservationNumber(reservationId);
        dxpRecommendationResponse.setRecommendationType("CalendarType");
        dxpRecommendationResponse.setDateTime(new Date());

        populateActivities(dxpActivities, nbxRecommendationResponse);
        List<DXPActivity> filteredList;
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(dxpActivities)
                && dxpActivities.size() >= (pageable.getPageSize() * pageable.getPageNumber())) {

            filteredList = Lists.partition(dxpActivities, pageable.getPageSize()).get(pageable.getPageNumber());
        } else {

            filteredList = new ArrayList<DXPActivity>();
        }
        dxpRecommendationResponse.setRecommendations(filteredList);
        list.add(dxpRecommendationResponse);
    }

    return dxpActivities;
}
#This method is used to populate data
private void populateActivities(List<DXPActivity> dxpActivities,
        NBXRecommendationResponse nbxRecommendationResponse) {

    for (Activity activity :nbxRecommendationResponse.getCalendarRecommendation().getRecommendations().getActivities()) {

        DXPActivity dxpActivity = new DXPActivity();
        orikaMapper.map(activity, dxpActivity);
        dxpActivities.add(dxpActivity);
    }
}
```

The response data:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "dXPRecommendationResponses": [
        {
            "recommendationType": "CalendarType",
            "reservationGuestId": "525dab66-1492-4908-a3bf-b5de558368e5",
            "reservationNumber": "3a39f9ad-7e34-4bdb-91eb-b907fd6986c7",
            "dateTime": "2019-08-19T14:38:18.413",
            "recommendations": [
            {
                "productCode": "BIKE2006111000",
                "activityName": "Bimini Bike Tour",
                "recommendationId": "1565948843492_410387839_BIKE2006111000_cal",
                "categoryCode": "DARING",
                "activityStartTime": "2020-06-11T08:30:00.000",
                "activityEndTime": "2020-06-11T11:30:00.000",
                "activityDescription": "Bimini Bike Tour",
                "sequence": 34.0,
                "packageId": 103806,
                "sourceId": "BIMINI BIKE",
                "levelOfActivity": "EASY"
            },
            {
                "productCode": "CUL2006110900",
                "activityName": "Bimini Culinary Tour",
                "recommendationId":"156594884349, 
                "categoryCode": "CULTURED",
                "activityStartTime": "2020-06-11T07:30:00.000",
                "activityEndTime": "2020-06-11T12:30:00.000",
                "activityDescription": "Bimini Culinary Tour",
                "sequence": 29.0,
                "packageId": 103940,
                "sourceId": "BIMINI CUL",
                "levelOfActivity": "MODERATE"
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 10,
        "totalElements": 1,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is implementation of `PageImpl` [constructor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImpl.java) and how the resulting total is being computed here. Below is code taken from the constructor:

```
this.total = pageable.toOptional().filter(it -> !content.isEmpty())//
        .filter(it -> it.getOffset() + it.getPageSize() > total)//
        .map(it -> it.getOffset() + content.size())//
        .orElse(total);
```

The important line here is second one, as described in doc comment, it is insurance against inconsistensies. It checks if you are on the last page and if so, it will use third line to compute resulting `total`. Therefore totally omitting `total` given by you. If you want to rewrite this behavior you should implement your `Page` which uses only given `total`.

BUT, I don't think it is semantically correct. You are mixing together things which probably should not be mixed (page object of one type, but the actual pagination done on another). The list given as pageable always has one element and you are paging subelements which does not seem right, is there even need to paginate the subelements?

One of the possible resolutions would be to make pageable only subelements by specifying `Page<DXPActivity> recommendations` member directly inside `DXPRecommendationResponse` and returning non-pageable `DXPRecommendationResponse`. But again, it seems a bit off. It really depens on what you are trying to build here and what is the logic behind that.